# onchange event not alerting

Tags: jquery, onchange

Could someone help me figure out why this isn't triggering?

```
$("input:radio[name=cm-fo-ozlkr]").change( function(){ 
             alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    });
```

HTML

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked" class="styled" value="1397935" id="cm1397935" name="cm-fo-ozlkr"><input type="radio" class="styled" value="1397934" id="cm1397934" name="cm-fo-ozlkr">
```

Comment: How are you assigning the event handler? on document ready?

Comment: It's working. What's the problem? Check out: http://jsbin.com/axura4/edit

Comment: yes i am, through jquery

Answer (score 2):

Your attribute selector was missing quotes;

```
$("input:radio[name='cm-fo-ozlkr']").change( function(){ 
             alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    });
```

Comment: Attribute selectors do not require quotes.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors Since the attribute value is not alphanumeric (hence the -) quotes are required according to w3c

Comment: Required as in up to the standard? Sure. Required as in his example doesn't work? Not even a little.

Comment: This is correct, but not for all browsers.  For instance, Google Chrome will allow a string with hyphens that isn't wrapped in quotes, but IE upto and including 9 will not.  I already added my +1 a while ago, but seeing the comments I thought I might throw in my 0.02.  As a best practice, always supply the quotes for an attribute selector.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Andy, I was not aware of the IE limitation!

Answer (score 2):

Is the radio button HTML getting generated dynamically e.g. on an ajax refresh? If so, you want to use jQuery live:

```
$("input:radio[name=cm-fo-ozlkr]").live('change', function () { 
    alert('Handler for .change() called.'); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `click` event instead of `change`.

Also, the correct selector is `input[name=cm-fo-ozlkr]:radio`.

Comment: +1 - The concept of a radio button list by shared name almost seems like kind of a hack; think of each radio button as a distinct item that just happens to make other radio buttons unselect as it is clicked.

Comment: The order of the attributes in the selector doesn't matter.  `input:radio[name=cm-fo-ozlkr]` is also correct.

Comment: His selector works fine and `click` is just not the same event as `change`. Not really an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:radio[name='cm-fo-ozlkr']").change( function(){ 
             alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you haven't already done so...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio[name=cm-fo-ozlkr]").change( function(){ 
             alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    });

});
```